# Given the following vector $X$, find a non-zero square matrix $A$ such that $AX=0$:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given the following vector X, find a non-zero square matrix $A$ such that $AX=0$:

So this problem stumped me and I've resorted to stack exchange. I need to find $A$, when I have a vertical vector $X = \left[4,2,-7\right]^T$

I've tried making an equation $a_1,a_2,a_3$ but the solution when I set it equal to $0$ is not easy to find since I have 2 even numbers and an odd. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint- Can you find a non-zero vector orthogonal to the given vector? e.g.: $(1,-2,0)$ is orthogonal to $X$.

Now set $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Then $AX=0$

Comment: Not sure I follow...sorry

Comment: Let me edit my answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Tip: If $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}4\\-2\\-7\end{pmatrix}=0 \iff \begin{pmatrix} 4a_{11} & -2a_{12} & -7a_{13} \\ 4a_{21} & -2a_{22} & -7a_{23}\\ 4a_{31} & -2a_{32} & -7a_{33}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Now give solutions for each row, notice that you have multiple solutions.

You can see the solution space for each row is a 2-dimensional vector space-, then you can give any value to $a_{i2}$, $a_{i3}$ and take $a_{i1}=\frac{1}{4}(2a_{i2}+7a_{i3})$ for $i=1,2,3$. (and this is just an example, you don't necessarily need to take $a_{i2}$ and $a_{i3}$, you can pick any two variables, give them some value and use them to find the other one).

Comment: Your answer was great too! Very intuitive.